# Angular JS: Function is not defined error in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, controller

In my `HomeCtrl.js` I am calling function `currentLocation()` from another function `initialize()` , I defined this fuction but it gives me an error of function is not defined :\ 
**Code Updated** But still same error occurred
Can anybody tell me what is the problem in my code?

**HomeCtrl.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Home').controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$state','MessageService', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService) {

    (function initialize(){
      var location = $scope.currentLocation();
      $scope.mapOptions = {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: location
      };
    })();
$scope.currentLocation = function(){

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                return $scope.position;               
            });
};

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it on top of the self-invoking function

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Home', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLocation = function() {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            return $scope.position;
        });
    };

    (function initialize() {
        var location = $scope.currentLocation();
        $scope.mapOptions = {
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: location
        };
    })();

});
```

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('Home', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLocation = function() {
    console.log("working")

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            return $scope.position;
        });
    };

    (function initialize() {
        var location = $scope.currentLocation();
        $scope.mapOptions = {
            mapTypeControl: true,
            zoom: 15, 
            center: location
        };
    })();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Home" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have added empty dependency to your module

Change

From

```
 angular.module('Home').controller('HomeCtrl',
```

To

```
 angular.module('Home',[]).controller('HomeCtrl',
```

Also the order of parameters is wrong, change it as

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Home').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$state','$ionicModal', 'MessageService', function ($scope, $state, $ionicModal, MessageService) {
   $scope.currentLocation = function() {
console.log("working")

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        return $scope.position;
    });
};

(function initialize() {
    var location = $scope.currentLocation();
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoom: 15, 
        center: location
    };
})();
}]);
```

Comment: I have update my code Please check ... still same error ocurred

Comment: @mariasalahuddin check with the updated controller in the answer

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.currentLocation` definition should be inside module.

Currently you are writing currentLocation outside module, hence it is not accessible.